# Having trouble with a SQL Server CE insertion function

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I've written the below function, which errors out correctly with non-int input and with int input returns that the audit was started properly. Unfortunately when I check the table I see that the data was never actually inserted.

Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong?

```
public string SqlLocation = "Data Source="+ new FileInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\DRAssistant.sdf");

public string StartAudit(string sqlLocation, string dps)
{
  int dpsInteger;
  if (!int.TryParse(dps, out dpsInteger))
    return "DPS is not a number!";

  try
  {
    var myConnection = new SqlCeConnection(sqlLocation);
    myConnection.Open();
    var myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
    myCommand.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT dps FROM DispatchReviews 
        WHERE dps = {0}", dpsInteger);
    SqlCeDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
      { return "DPS review has already started!"; }

    myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DispatchReviews (dps, starttime, 
        reviewer) VALUES (@dps, @starttime, @reviewer)";

    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dps", dpsInteger);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starttime", DateTime.Now);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reviewer", Environment.UserName);
    myCommand.Prepare();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    myCommand.Dispose();
    myConnection.Close();
    return "Dispatch Review Started!";
    }
  catch(Exception ex)
    { return "Unable to save DPS!" + ex.Message; }
  }
```

Edit: Turns out this was just an idiot problem--which anybody looking at the SqlLocation could probably figure out--in that every time I built the application a new copy of the .sdf was copied into the application directory, overwriting the previous one. Also, the database I was checking for updates was not the one in the execution directory, but the one that was being copied into it, which is why it was always empty. I noticed this because when I tried to add the same DPS multiple times the first time I would get the DPS review started message, but subsequent attempts would give the error that it had previously been created.

Comment: Can you please show us your **connection string**?? Most likely, if you test this inside Visual Studio, the database file is being copied around (from your initial directory to the output directory where the app runs) and your INSERT might work just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong file**....

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but you really should consider creating your connection, reader command objects within `using` statements to ensure they are correctly disposed of.

Comment: You have 2 return values that state the review has started.  Are you sure that the value you see isn't `DPS review has already started!` when you're actually looking for `Dispatch Review Started!`

Comment: Marc_s: I added the connection string. I know it's right, though, because I initially misspelled the table name and received a runtime error stating the table could not be found. Once I fixed the name it went away--so clearly it's able to locate the file and is able to see the tables that exist within it.

Quinton: Yes, it's returning Dispatch Review Started! I've also checked the database table to verify that it is empty, so there's really no way it could be getting into that if block anyway.

Comment: why you didn't close the connection?

Comment: Hossein: I've added it. All: Turns out the insertion was working fine, I was just being stupid in not correctly checking for it. I've updated the original post with a description of what the problem was. Marc_S: You were right in your initial comment, I just didn't realize what you meant. Please answer the question as such and I'll mark that as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben: added my comment as an answer - glad I was able to help sort it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please show us your connection string??

**Most likely**, if you test this inside Visual Studio, the database file is being copied around (from your initial directory to the output directory where the app runs) and your `INSERT` will probably work just fine - but you're just looking at the wrong file when you check that fact.